# What is the non-European perception of Marie-Curie postdoctoral fellowships?

Tags: funding, international, reputation, marie-curie

I recently posted the above question along with another in the same post and was asked to post this one separately.

I have received a Marie-Curie individual fellowship from the European Commission. As a non-European, this allows me to take up research in a Member State. I know this fellowship is prestigious in Europe, but I'm not sure how it's perceived in other parts of the world like the USA, Canada, Australia...etc. Any idea on this?

Comment: This seems very opinion-based. In general, the best way to find out how prestigious X is is to see what the people currently or formerly   affiliated with X are doing.

Comment: Seems to be this: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/108216/can-i-deviate-from-my-fellowship-proposal

Answer (score 11):

Speaking as a researcher in the USA, I would say that [Marie Skłodowska-Curie Actions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marie_Sk%C5%82odowska-Curie_Actions) are clearly perceived as having significant prestige.
Even not knowing all of the details, one immediately sees:

1. It's an EU-wide program, and those generally have high competition.
2. Curie remains widely famous, and nations and organizations are protective of her name.

Exactly how prestigious it is compared to other prestigious fellowships I wouldn't care to speculate, but it's clearly a noteworthy addition to any researcher's CV.

Answer (score 6):

While I was in China and Korea between 2014 and 2017, I was fortunate to chair several selection panels for early-career academics. We received applications (not many, maybe half a doze or so) from researchers who'd completed Marie Sklodowska-Curie Fellowships. We rated them about as well as any other internationally competitive postdoctoral fellowship. We certainly ranked them higher than typical national fellowships, but not by much. We were more interested in the candidate's accomplishments as a Marie Sklodowska-Curie Fellow rather than their receiving one in the first place.

I suggest that you make the most of the opportunity by collecting great data, presenting at the top conferences in your field, delivering workshops and classes on your area of expertise and publishing solid research in the peer-reviewed publications in your discipline.

Good luck to you.